# Have there been any changes to the Automatic Bell Dispenser since City Folk?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I'm curious to know which features, if any, have changed regarding the Automatic Bell Dispenser that acts as a bank in the Animal Crossing series.

So far, I've noticed:

- Is located in the Post Office and on the tropical Island
- Still rewards a tissue box after depositing 100,000 Bells... and presumably the other subsequent rewards as well.
- Shopping card feature appears to have been removed.

Could anyone offer a comprehensive list of ABD features in New Leaf?  Also, can anyone confirm if you are still rewarded interest at the beginning of each month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://acwiki3ds.wikispaces.com/Post+Office

I had to check it myself after I got the piggy bank at 1,000,000 Bells instead of the 10,000,000 it was in ACWW.

I can confirm that you receive 0.5% interest on the first of each month (I received 20,000 Bells on 8/1/13 for 4,000,000 in the bank).

Unfortunately I only have 7,000,000 in the bank so I cannot confirm anything past the aluminum case reward (which is indeed at 5,000,000 Bells). What strikes my interest is that you only have to save up 100,000,000 Bells to get all rewards, so it is quite feasible to simply save up that much money at the beginning of the game before doing anything else.

Update: Confirmed all rewards (ADB @ 100,000,000 Bells)

Answer (score -1):

Comprehensive Outlook on : *ABD NEW LEAF*

The Automatic Bell Dispenser (ABD) or ATM in Japanese releases is available within Animal Crossing New Leaf via

- Post Office with Pelly and Phyllis running 24/7 at the Town Center above Town.
- An ABD Machne Completing the deposit tasks (This ABD Machine cannot be bought in store but can be sold, so acquiring it is hard and selling by your part has no restriction so be careful about its placement outside since Villagers can prop a house one day and plant it over the items.)

Suggestion: (If you want to be completing the ABD requirements faster, try accumulating all the funds into one account and retrieve a certain quantity for the other Villager after amounting to ABD beneficial interests.)

- Each Villager in the town will receive an according to the amount that is deposited in their account only ever once.
- Animal Crossing New Leaf Japan Received a 7-Eleven ABD that allows a complete 24/7 access to the Bells stored in the Players Home. (Not sure if other Players can access this but it should accommodate) (It is by my regards unclear if it can be ordered by catalog, but youtube's wiifolderjosh has a video in which the DLC are regularly priced)

(Suggestion: find a friend or an acquaintance that can trade with you items from Japanese DLCs)

- The Featured Game Island run by the Kapp'n family.
- (not sure about CLUB TORTIMER; might be something different as its also an island feature used in the game.)

List of Items Available

- 100,000 || Box of Tissues
- 500,000 || Letter Set
- 1,000,000 || Piggy Bank
- 5,000,000 || Aluminum Case
- 10,000,000 || Post Office Poster
- 20,000,000 || Safe
- 50,000,000 || Delivery Person Hat
- 100,000,000 || ABD (24/7 Account)

(This is much more beneficiary than WW and CF as they both had players deposit 10%-50% more for each accessible item as the feather was featured as a gimmick collection)

One day from the month after first deposit, the .5% increase in bonused (most likely after the player enters; most noticeably from CF [[another player may not gain any bell bonuses on that day simply by not entering but another player who played does]]).

About the ABD Card Bonuses. Since GracieGrace and the Able Sister are not featured together & Each store character has a mild distaste for futuristic accounts the card may have dissolved all together. The feature was called a shopping card and each player was given one after completing a task in previous games. The tools are Shopping Card & Shopping Card Gold. These were useful only for the more expensive stores/outlets which are
 - Gracie's Store
 - Auction House
Because it may have taken some memory input it took up game functions and may have been pulled due to the minimal functions of a 3DS cartridge and its minimal adaptation by characters from CITY FOLK. They don't need to be considered defunct though as the new Wii U game for Animal Crossing may feature this if enough outcry from followers of the game ask the creators to add this feature in to help with Bell storage.

Try getting 3DS friend codes as many people ARE in fact playing this, most notably on the tumblr platform under the any of the tumblr hashtag new leaf [tumblr com / tagged / new leaf] There are a lot of GameFAQ users playing. Twitter's [ACNLFC](https://twitter.com/ACNLFC) has MANY 3DS codes from bloggers/players all across the nation and various continents and continually updates faster than twitter feeds. [find those posting fcs so get their link before refreshing as they might not be visibly posted after 1 minute]

**This is all the information I could amass from threads and by my own knowledge of the game.**

Comment: We don't mind links to wikis and whatnot, but telling people to go to a different place to ask questions is crossing the line.